# Parse string to store lead_id as a variable

Tags: php

I need to extract the **$lead_id** here when this is returned to me from an endpoint. What you are looking at here is part of the actual source code of the endpoint I am sending a GET request to

```
echo "$result: $result_reason - $phone_number|$list_id|$lead_id|$gmt_offset|$user\n";
```

Here is an example of what is returned to me: **SUCCESS: add_lead LEAD HAS BEEN ADDED - 27000000000|6015|81527|2|9000** and I need to store this lead_id, 81527, as a variable on my end

Comment: Any specific reason you return the result this way? Why not return it in a more readable format like JSON?

Comment: Unfortunately the endpoint I am sending my request to cannot return the response in JSON

Comment: That's unfortunate, would make life a little easier. You can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to explode the string to an array, then get the part you need

Comment: You are 100% correct, actually also just came to mind that I can explode based on the pipe characters as this is always consistent in the response

Comment: @brombeer just tested print_r (explode("|",$str)); and working perfectly. Can you post your answer so I can accept the as the answer?

Comment: Nah we're good, you kind of figured it out yourself. ;) Just delete the question